# IdleX in "pip list" but I cannot access it from command window

Tags: python, package, python-idle

So I have manually installed the latest version of IdleX (1.18) and it is working fine. But I cannot access it the via the command window like I would with jupyter.

How do I add this functionality (it is already showing up on pip list)

Comment: are jupyter and your python from the CLI pointing to the same python environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out the reason, IdleX doesn't use a .exe in the Scripts file (like jupyter does with jupyter.exe).

Instead it uses a .py file and thus to call it from the command prompt you would write "idlex.py" (without the commas)